# Sessions ASP.NET Timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, session-timeout

I have problems with sessions in asp.net. I searched the web for a while, but couldn't find the reason why it doesn't works. The session disappears after some minutes. It is a project that isn't created by myself, i'm not a hero in aspx. But I'm trying to solve this problem.

**Web.config**

```
 <system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="120" slidingExpiration="true" />
     </authentication>

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false" />

    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="120"  />

  </system.web>
```

**Checking if Logged in on the pages that you have to be logged in**
     if (!functions.isLoggedIn(Session))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
                }
**Functions**

```
public static bool isLoggedIn(HttpSessionState session)
        {
            return session["user"] != null;
        }
```

**Not logged in ? Showing login form, filling in the form and then send it to server to check**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       if (Request["do"] != null)
        {
            switch (Request["do"])
            {
                case "logout":
                    Session.Abandon();
                    break;
            }
        }
     if (Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"].ToLower() == "post")
                {
                    //get username en password
                    string username = Request["username"];
                    string password = Request["password"];
                    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
                    {
                        LoginMessage.Text = "Please fill in all the fields...";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        password = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(
                                password,
                                "SHA1");
                            UserService gs = new UserService();
                            user g = gs.getUserByLogin(username, password);
                        if (g == null)
                        {
                            //wrong login
                            LoginMessage.Text = "Invalid username/password.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //good login
                            Session["user"] = g;
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timeout:" + Session.Timeout);
                            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
                        }
                   }
    }
}
```

**GetUserByLogin function in userservice**

```
public user getUserByLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            user g;
            var db = new projectName.Db.Models.projectnetContext();

            IQueryable<user> query = from gb in db.users
                where gb.username.Equals(username)
                      && gb.Passwoord.Equals(password.ToLower())
                      && gb.Status == 1
                select gb;

            if (!query.Any())
                g = null;
            else
                g = query.First();

            return g;
        }
```

**After login in, creating the session**

```
Session["user"] = g;
```

My problem is that I have set the time-out. But it doesn't seems to work. If I check the timeout on the server, it is set to 120. But after 2 minutes, I'm redirected to the login form. Can I solve this? If I debug on localhost, It seems to work, but not online.

The login works. The session is set (otherwise I couldn't enter the next pages). If I go to another page (faster then +-5minutes), then I'm still logged in. So the problem is reproductive.

Or if it isn't possible, Cookies? Normally I work with cookies in PHP,.. But is there a way to do it in ASP.NET on a safe way?

Comment: I wrote this article long ago, and I hope it helps you out... http://aspalliance.com/1182_Troubleshooting_Session_Related_Issues_in_ASPNET

Comment: According to your configuration session values are stored inProc so depend also of w3wp.exe process. If the applicationPool restarted sessions was lost.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this. After uploading the project to the webserver, I logged in again. But the problem stays. Since uploading to the server, I didn't changed something else.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I Recommend you to use profile instead of session in asp .net .

Answer (score 0):

There is two aspects in your scenario. You have the authentication and the session. These are two different things.

Session that you are manage in your web.config stored a value with a timeout of 120 minutes (2 hours)

But Authentication also have a configuration section in web.config.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So what do you want to do exactly first ?

Comment: I already used the authentication in the web.config. Now I added it to the global post. The timeout of this was also set to 120.

Comment: Ok, but how do you authenticate the user ? You haven't post any code most how you do ... Can you post this code ?

Comment: I have added some extra code. What happens after filling in the login form,... Still something missing?

Comment: I will post an sample of a POC project use Forms Authentication to illustrate what I tried to explain you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please find this MVC controller action method sample.

```
    // POST: /Secure/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginFormModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Login, model.Password))
            {
                using (var db = new DatabaseEntities())
                {
                    var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Login == model.Login);

                    Membership.UpdateUser(new MembershipUser("UserMembershipProvider", user.Login, null, null, null, null, true, false, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.Now, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MinValue));

                    #region Create Authentication Cookie

                    Response.Cookies.Add(MyAppFormAuthenticationCookie.Create(user, model.RememberMe));

                    #endregion

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(returnUrl));
                    }

                    if (model.UserFormType == UserType.Candidate)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Candidate" });
                    }

                    if (model.UserFormType == UserType.Recruiter)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Recruiter" });
                    }

                    if (model.UserFormType == UserType.SuperAdmin || model.UserFormType == UserType.Admin)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Admin" });
                    }
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username and/or password");
            return View("Index", model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

In this sample, you have :

- UPDATE of the user profile to set the last connection date and others if you want ...
- CREATION of the authentication cookie in a custom way for this sample
- REDIRECTION to the homepage according to the type of user

So, do you have a similar approach to authenticate user in your application ?

EDIT1:

Normally you must finalize authentication process something like this :

```
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket("MyAuthTicket", rememberMe, timeout: 120);
        var encryptAuthTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptAuthTicket) { Expires = authTicket.Expiration });
```

Comment: The part where I authenticate the user is in the 3rd code blok (global post). I have nothing more?

Comment: But authentication can't just be a check of the login/password against database object. You must keep the authentication token and this must be done thanks to FormsAuthentication. Please see the EDIT1

Comment: So I don't use authentication, or am I wrong? The only thing I do is store g in the session user and i have also FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile

Comment: Yes you authenticate the user but you don't give him the ticket which allow him to proof his authentication. It can work but it is not secure and reliable. Yeah, I've seen that you used FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile but as you can read in the MSDN documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.hashpasswordforstoringinconfigfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it is not to authenticate a user, it is just to encrypt the password as you have done probably to register the user.

Comment: Ok, I will read the documentation and give it a try in the coming days.

Answer (score -2):

Just an advice... do you have any re-directions(Response.Redierct) to diff. sites or trying to access the resources for which you don't have access? Session will expire in these cases.

Comment: Yes, I have redirections (after checking if user is logged in (= session set)). But it is to a page in the same site, the login form page (=default.aspx)

Comment: can you change it to Server.Transfer if you are using Response.Redirect and give it a try.

Comment: Hmms, Like you can see in the global post, it is only after checking the session. Not before. --> functions.isLoggedIn(Session).

Comment: Even if the response.redirect go to another website, session won't be lost because session was attached to server so can't be lost since the user close his browser ;-)